# Show that the decimal number obtained by concatenating the digits of n! successively represents an irrational number.

Tags: decimal-expansion

Show that the decimal number
$0.12624120720...$
obtained by concatenating the digits of $n!$ successively with $n =
1, 2, 3, ...$ represents an irrational number.

A rational number either has a terminating decimal expansion or an eventually repeating decimal expansion. $0.12624120720... $ is clearly not a terminating sequence. $n!$ is unique for each $n \in \mathbb N$ But how do we prove that uniqueness means non-repeating here?

Comment: That was asked very recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527848/show-that-0-12624120720-is-irrational

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: can you prove that there are arbitrarily long sequences of zeroes - eventually longer than any claimed finite period?

Comment: I have shown that the highest power of $10$ dividing $N!$ is the highest power of $5$ dividing $N!$. How do I go further?